# Клонироване объектов с ограничением по координатам

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объект который я клонирую с помощью такого скрипта

```
public GameObject enemy;
void Start() {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
Instantiate(enemy);
}
}
```

мне бы хотелось ограничить это клонирование по координатам, то есть я хочу чтобы мои клоны находились в определенном пространстве на сцене. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ограничивайте, в чем проблема то?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но мне бы хотелось увидеть, как это реализовано в коде.

Comment: Дело в том, что вы озвучили свою задачу, но никак не показали, как вы сами пытались эту задачу решить. Но если вы сами не пробовали решить свою задачу, зачем кому то пробовать это делать для вас? Вот когда вы что то попытаетесь, и у вас не получится, вот тогда есть смысл спрашивать, а пока нет проблемы - нет ответов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у Instantiate есть еще несколько параметров, там можно указать позицию и поворот сразу.

```
void RandomGenEnemy(GameObject enemy,int count,Vector3 downLeftNear, Vector3 upRightFar)
{
    Vector3 pos;
    for(int i=0;i< count; i++)
    {
        pos.x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(downLeftNear.x, upRightFar.x);
        pos.y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(downLeftNear.y, upRightFar.y);
        pos.z = UnityEngine.Random.Range(downLeftNear.z, upRightFar.z);
        Instantiate(enemy, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Область задается в виде 3D куба(если надо только 2D, убирай одну ось(например y))

**Vector3 downLeftNear;** - нижний левый ближаший угол 3D куба(координаты должны быть меньше, чем у upRightFar)

**Vector3 upRightFar;** - верхний правый дальний угол 3D куба